# Unable to do security updates on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: updates, update-manager

It's that the update would have me installing things from an unsecured source. When I go to the update manager and only select the security updates instead of the recommended updates as well I still get the same result. When I hit more info when the error pops up it says

```
"accountsservice apt apt-transport-https apt-utils curl fonts-opensymbol 
gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-desktop3-data gnupg gpgv 
landscape-client-ui-install libaccountsservice0 libapt-inst1.4 libapt-pkg4.12 
libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl3-nss libdjvulibre-text libdjvulibre21 
libgnome-control-center1 libgnome-desktop-3-2 libjpeg-turbo8 libopenjpeg2 
libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-script 
libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-svg libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns 
libqtcore4 libqtgui4 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common 
libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-emailmerge libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math 
libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-style-tango libreoffice-writer 
linux-firmware pm-utils python-uno qdbus rsyslog software-center uno-libs3 ure"
```

Any ideas on whats going on and what I can do for it?

I don't like not updating my security.

Answer (score 0):

What "unsecured source" are you seeing updates from?  What lead you to that conclusion?  I'm going to take a guess at answering what I think is your question:

```
Why are ubuntu update sources using http instead of https?
```

In short, they are secure.  The [wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SecureApt) for  SecureApt explains, "Apt-get package management uses public key cryptography to authenticate downloaded packages."  Here is a wonderful post that explains another way: [Are repository lists secure? Is there an HTTPS version?](https://askubuntu.com/a/352972/192800)

What you've listed as an error is a list of [packages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware).  This does not show that there is a problem.  If there is a problem, editing your question with the output from this command (via [Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal)) will show it:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

For reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu