# Is there a roadmap for https support for ppas?

Tags: ppa, https

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu, and just realised that all my ppa's I've been adding are http only

Are there plans for https support in the future?

Comment: Highly unlikely, for the same reasons as in http://askubuntu.com/questions/352952/are-repository-lists-secure-is-there-an-https-version

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thats for the Ubuntu repository lists, that doesn't apply to PPA's does it?

Comment: It applies to PPAs as well if the maintainer signs the published packages which is usually the case.

Comment: @DavidFoerster You can't upload an unsigned package to a PPA. Signature is mandatory. So it is not "usually" the case. It is always the case.

Comment: @Pilot6: AFAIK that's true for Launchpad PPAs but not all Apt-compatible package repositories in general.

Comment: @DavidFoerster The question was about PPAs, that's Launcpad. And I don't think that `apt` allows to install unsigned packages from anywhere.

Comment: @Pilot6: I see you haven't discovered the `--allow-unauthenticated` option yet. :-]

Answer (score 0):

There is no need in https because all packages in PPA are signed with GPG.

So it does not matter where do you download the packages from if you are sure that they are authentic.